# Retrieve JUnit tests results with python

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, junit

I'm looking for a way to run JUnit tests and get the results (whatever the format or the structure) in python. My first guess has been to use JPype, but I would like to know if you know any simpler solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to extract tests results with a combination of surefire XML reports along with the `lxml` python module. To use the intermediate XML reports seems to be the easiest yet the most efficient method.